# Does bitcoin-wallet support BIP148

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-wallet-app, bip148-uasf

Does anyone know if bitcoin-wallet on Andriod (https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet) supports BIP148?

I've been Googling and checked their GitHub page but I can't find BIP148 mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIP148 isn't relevant any more, since BIP91 has activated on July 23.